# any sample for batch processing in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, persistence, spring-batch, batch-processing

Can i find the example of batch processing in java hibernate so that i can run delete queries on two tables.

Comment: i have two tables. in both tables having a common field. i want to run a query that delete the record from both tables on the basis of  common field. for this i want to execute a batch query.

Comment: please update your original post (by clicking "edit" above), rather than adding content in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the relevant chapter of the [Hibernate Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/batch.html).

Answer (score 2):

The documentation includes a chapter about DML-style operations:

> #### [13.4. DML-style operations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct)
>
> As already discussed, automatic and
>   transparent object/relational mapping
>   is concerned with the management of
>   the object state. The object state is
>   available in memory. This means that
>   manipulating data directly in the
>   database (using the SQL Data
>   Manipulation Language  (DML) the
>   statements: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)
>   will not affect in-memory state.
>   However, Hibernate provides methods
>   for bulk SQL-style DML statement
>   execution that is performed through
>   the Hibernate Query Language (HQL).
>
> The pseudo-syntax for UPDATE and
>   DELETE statements is: `( UPDATE | DELETE ) 
>   FROM? EntityName (WHERE where_conditions)?`.
>
> Some points to note:
>
> - In the from-clause, the FROM keyword is optional
> - There can only be a single entity named in the from-clause. It can,
>     however, be aliased. If the entity
>     name is aliased, then any property
>     references must be qualified using
>     that alias. If the entity name is not
>     aliased, then it is illegal for any
>     property references to be qualified.
> - **No joins**, either implicit or explicit, can be specified in a bulk
>     HQL query. Sub-queries can be used in
>     the where-clause, where the subqueries
>     themselves may contain joins.
> - The where-clause is also optional.
>
> (...)
>
> To execute an HQL DELETE, use the
>   same `Query.executeUpdate()`  method:
>
> ```
> Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
> Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
>
> String hqlDelete = "delete Customer c where c.name = :oldName";
> // or String hqlDelete = "delete Customer where name = :oldName";
> int deletedEntities = s.createQuery( hqlDelete )
>         .setString( "oldName", oldName )
>         .executeUpdate();
> tx.commit();
> session.close();
> ```
>
> The int value returned by the
>   `Query.executeUpdate()` method
>   indicates the number of entities
>   effected by the operation. This may or
>   may not correlate to the number of
>   rows effected in the database. An HQL
>   bulk operation might result in
>   multiple actual SQL statements being
>   executed (for joined-subclass, for
>   example). The returned number
>   indicates the number of actual
>   entities affected by the statement.
>   Going back to the example of
>   joined-subclass, a delete against one
>   of the subclasses may actually result
>   in deletes against not just the table
>   to which that subclass is mapped, but
>   also the "root" table and potentially
>   joined-subclass tables further down
>   the inheritance hierarchy.

I'm not sure what you mean by *so that I can run delete queries on two tables* though. Keep in mind that bulk operations don't cascade, as documented.